# Allowing a non-root user to restart a service

Tags: systemd, jenkins

**Background :**

I created an app called `myapp` with `Spring-boot`. It consists of a self-executable jar and is compatible with systemd services. Now, I am trying to integrate it with jenkins.

**What I want:**

I want jenkins to be able to :

- stop the service.
- replace the jar.
- restart the service.

**Problem:**

Up to now, only sudoers can start/stop services. I don't want jenkins to be a sudoer (it seems messy).

**Current structure:**

I have a user `myapp` which has a `/home/myapp` folder. The generated jar is called `myapp` and is placed at `/home/myapp`. The user `myapp` is the owner of the generated jar:

```
myapp@myserver:~/backend$ ll
total 53900
drwxrwxr-x 2 myapp myapp     4096 Apr 25 17:09 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 myapp myapp     4096 Apr 25 17:08 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myapp myapp      511 Apr 20 16:13 application.properties
-rwxr--r-- 1 myapp myapp 55175294 Apr 20 19:06 backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myapp myapp       24 Apr 20 19:20 myapp -> backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar*
-rw-r--r-- 1 myapp myapp      179 Apr 20 19:26 myapp.service
```

I placed a ssh key so that jenkins can log as `myapp@myserver`.

As `myapp` is the owner of the jar, I think that there might be an option that allows the user `myapp` to call `systemctl start/stop myapp`. Actually, I can call `systemctl status myapp` but not `start/stop` (root password is asked).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see the reason to consider `sudo` messy, it is generally the way you should be implementing something like this. Create a group, assign your jenkins user to it and using `visudo` provide a limited command set to that group for managing the service

Comment: @brent Is there a way to allow `myapp` to call `sudo systemctl` only for its own service?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`sudo` is the way to go. Create a new group (`appadmin` for example), put your `jenkins` user in it, and using `visudo` add a new entry with a limited list of commands, for example:

```
Cmnd_Alias MYAPP_CMNDS = /bin/systemctl start myapp, /bin/systemctl stop myapp
%appadmin ALL=(ALL) MYAPP_CMNDS
```

If you want the `appadmin` group to be able to operate the service without entering a password first (useful if the user is only authenticated by an SSH key for example),

```
Cmnd_Alias MYAPP_CMNDS = /bin/systemctl start myapp, /bin/systemctl stop myapp
%appadmin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: MYAPP_CMNDS
```

Comment: Don't forget the statement order https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13058/86443