# Unable to restart a systemctl service remotely as a non root user

Tags: sudo, systemd, socket, gunicorn, systemctl

I have a *systemd.socket* named **gunicorn.socket** which I would like to restart after updating some code on a remote server.

I've followed the steps detailed in [Allowing a non-root user to restart a service](https://serverfault.com/a/772786/135885) and `systemctl` keeps asking for my user password. Here is what I've done trying to run `systemctl restart gunicorn.socket` with user `john`:

```
# added an appadmin group to allow the restart command to john
addgroup appadmin
usermod -a -G appadmin john
visudo
```

In `sudoers`:

```
Cmnd_Alias MYAPP_CMNDS = /bin/systemctl start gunicorn.socket, /bin/systemctl stop gunicorn.socket, /bin/systemctl restart gunicorn.socket
%appadmin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: MYAPP_CMNDS
```

Then `sudo systemctl restart gunicorn.socket` works fine while being on the server, but when I try it remotely I get:

```
ssh example.com "sudo systemctl restart gunicorn.socket"
Failed to restart gunicorn.socket: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status gunicorn.socket' for details.
```

Any ideas? I'm using Ubuntu 17.04.

**Update:** adding full content of `/etc/sudoers`:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias MYAPP_CMNDS = /bin/systemctl start gunicorn.socket, /bin/systemctl stop gunicorn.socket, /bin/systemctl restart gunicorn.socket
%appadmin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: MYAPP_CMNDS

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
john        ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the 'requiretty' option is not set in /etc/sudoers.

See this question for more information: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/how-to-disable-requiretty-for-a-single-command-in-sudoers

Comment: No `requiretty` present in `/etc/sudoers`. Also tried with `Defaults:john        !requiretty` without luck.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable answer: why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to move the block:

`# Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias MYAPP_CMNDS = /bin/systemctl start gunicorn.socket, /bin/systemctl stop gunicorn.socket, /bin/systemctl restart gunicorn.socket
%appadmin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: MYAPP_CMNDS`

to the end of the file. The order of permission blocks in `/etc/sudoers` is not trivial. From the `sudoers` man page, thanks to [@enzotib](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100051/why-is-sudoers-nopasswd-option-not-working):

```
When multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order.
Where there are multiple matches, the last match is used (which is not
necessarily the most specific match).
```